# shell script to Start/Stop tomcat server

Tags: bash, shell, tomcat, sh

I am trying to stop and start tomcat using shell script on linux server.
Below is shell script i copied from internet but it is not working. I am new for shell scripting.
Please can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

export BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.47/bin
prog=apache-tomcat-8.5.47

stat() {
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat is running.
else
echo Tomcat is not running.
fi
}

case "$1" in
start)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
echo Tomcat seems to be running. Use the restart option.
else
$BASE/startup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
fi
stat
;;
stop)
$BASE/shutdown.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
stat
;;
restart)

if [ `ps auxwwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
for pid in `ps auxwww|grep $prog|grep -v grep|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2`
do
kill -9 $pid 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
fi
$BASE/startup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
stat
;;
status)
stat
;;
*)
echo "Usage: tomcat start|stop|restart|status"
esac
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @RushiDaxini No errors, after running shell script printing this
**Usage: tomcat start|stop|restart|status**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below step:

- Save provided code in `.sh` file (i.e. StartStopScript.sh) at one location.
- Update `export BASE` variable with you tomcat bin location.
- Update `prog` variable with tomcat version.
- **IMPORTANT:** run the script with argument eg.

`StartStopScript.sh start` to start the server

`StartStopScript.sh stop` to stop the server

`StartStopScript.sh restart` to restart the server

`StartStopScript.sh status` to check server status